# Cell should contain example input value for user to see

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create automated cells in Excel which will show the type of data to be entered in that cells. I want to create cells which will show "Enter Username here", " Enter DOB here" same as that which shows in fb and Gmail login page. I don't want to save any credentials.

I had created multiple dropdown lists and people are not understanding that there is a dropdown until they click on that cell. So I want to create automated cells which will show the type of data to be entered into it. It should disappear when I click on that cell and should appear if I erase the contents from that cell which I anyone had entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the change selection event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    if target.address = "$A$1" then
         target.value = ""
    else
         Dim value as string
         value = range("$A$1").value
         if value="" then   'Note: It'd be better to check here if the user input is correct!
             range("$A$1").value = "Enter DOB here"
         end if
    end if
End Sub
```

Edit to user's comments:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    if target.address = "$A$1" then
         if target.value = "Enter DOB here"
             target.value = ""
         end if
    else
         Dim value as string
         value = range("$A$1").value
         if value="" then   'Note: It'd be better to check here if the user input is correct!
             range("$A$1").value = "Enter DOB here"
         end if
    end if
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sancarn. Everything is working fine expect one thing. When i am clicking back on that cell it is resetting into blank cell. How to stop it from resetting into blank cell.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? you just put another if statement in place of where `target.value = ""` is... See the edit